# How do i replicate this radio button design in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a radio list tile I am trying to rebuild the UI :

[image]

If you see the picture, you'll notice, on selected radio, the whole container turns pale blue and the radio button is big enough with it's colors.

I have tried using `RadioListTile` in a stateful widget but I'm really stuck in the whole config and UI.

This is my code :

```
Container(
                        child: Row(
                          children: [
                            Text('Some details are incorrect'),
                            RadioListTile(
                                activeColor: Color(0xffF8F8F8),
                                value: 1,
                                groupValue: 1,
                                onChanged: (value) {}),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                      Container(
                        child: Row(
                          children: [
                            Text('I didn’t make this order'),
                            RadioListTile(
                                activeColor: Color(0xffF8F8F8),
                                value: 1,
                                groupValue: 1,
                                onChanged: (value) {}),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                      Container(
                        child: Row(
                          children: [
                            Text('Request came in too late'),
                            RadioListTile(
                                activeColor: Color(0xffF8F8F8),
                                value: 1,
                                groupValue: 1,
                                onChanged: (value) {}),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
```

This code keeps giving me errors and I don't know where I am getting it wrong.

Comment: you can use AnimatedContainer on ListTile

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use container with decoration on ListTile.

```dart
class MyWr2 extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyWr2({super.key});

  @override
  State<MyWr2> createState() => _MyWr2State();
}

class _MyWr2State extends State<MyWr2> {
  String? selectedItem;
  List<String> items = ["A", "B", "C"];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        children: items
            .map((e) => ListTile(
                  onTap: () {
                    setState(() {
                      selectedItem = e;
                    });
                  },
                  title: Text(e),
                  trailing: AnimatedContainer(
                    duration: Duration(milliseconds: 100),
                    width: 20,
                    height: 20,
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      shape: BoxShape.circle,
                      border: Border.all(
                        color:
                            selectedItem == e ? Colors.deepPurple : Colors.grey,
                        width: selectedItem == e ? 5 : 3,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ))
            .toList(),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you sir for this reply, how do i change the row color when a radio is selected? like in the case of the picture i gave?

Comment: you mean the full tile?  you can use `tileColor: selectedItem == e ? ColorsA : ColorB,` on `ListTile`

Comment: Life saver! always coming true at my hard times.. i really appreciate, i'll now have to learn your logic and customize to my desire

Comment: Sir, please i have a similar question i asked on here for weeks now that has not been answered, if you are free you can help me with that

Comment: Ok I will check if i can, can you include the link

Comment: This is the link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75199715/how-do-i-set-a-checkbox-to-select-and-deselect-other-checkboxes-in-flutter